# Parse options with binary masks

Tags: c

and good evening! I am currently creating an executable for linux. However, when parsing the options of my executable, I encounter errors.

I  do not understand why the "-p" option passes the verification conditions..

The header file my project:

```
# define O_LONG         0x6c // -l
# define O_RECUR        0x52 // -R
# define O_ALL          0x61 // -a
# define O_SORT         0x72 // -r
# define O_R_SORT       0x74 // -t

# define O_MSK_LONG             1
# define O_MSK_REC              2
# define O_MSK_ALL              4
# define O_MSK_SORT             8
# define O_MSK_R_SORT           16
```

My function that parses the options: (`option` -> number X program argument, and `options` is a pointer to my result)

```
int     parse_option(int *options, char *option)
{
    char    flag;

    option++; // To pass the first character -
    while ((flag = *(char*)option))
    {
        if ((O_ALL & flag) == flag)
            *options |= O_MSK_ALL;
        else if ((O_RECUR & flag) == flag)
            *options |= O_MSK_REC;
        else if ((O_SORT & flag) == flag)
            *options |= O_MSK_SORT;
        else if ((flag & O_R_SORT) == flag)
            *options |= O_MSK_R_SORT;
        else if ((O_LONG & flag) == flag)
            *options |= O_MSK_LONG;
        else {
            printf("command: invalid option -- '%c'\n", flag);
            return (-1);
        }
        printf("%c %i\n", flag, *options);
        option++;
    }
    return (1);
}
```

Comment: Why not `O_LONG == flag`?

Comment: Pleas make a [mcve].

Comment: Also, your code doesn't skip spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'r' is `0x72` and 'p' is `0x70` so if `flag = 0x70`, then `flag & O_SORT`  = `0x70 & 0x72` = `0x70` = `flag`. You should modify the conditions to `if (flag == O_SOMETHING) {...}`.